# Count Aggregation on filtered nested object giving incorrect result

Tags: elasticsearch

Our Elastic Mapping

```
> {"mappings": {
>         "products" : {
>           "properties":{
>             "name " : {
>               "type" : "keyword"
>             },
>             "resellers" : { 
>                 "type" : "nested",
>                 "properties" : {
>                     "name" : { "type" : "text" },
>                     "price" : { "type" : "double" }
>                 }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>     }}
```

In this mapping each product stores the list of resellers which are selling it at specific price. We have requirment to find all distinct prices of specific reseller.
As per my understanding we need to have query DSL which should first have nested filter on given reseller and then apply count aggregation. We have formed following ES query for ES 5.6 version:-

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "resellers",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "match_phrase_prefix": {
                            "resellers.name": "flipkart"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "narrow": {
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "resellers",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": {
                                "term": {
                                    "resellers.name": "flipkart"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "state": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "resellers"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "count": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "resellers.price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query is generating incorrect output. Output also contain price of other resellers which are present in elastic documents ( like Amazon,Snapdeal etc). Can somebody help to correct query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query instead (i.e. filter inside the nested aggregation, not outside of it):

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "resellers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "resellers.name": "flipkart"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "resellers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "narrow": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "resellers.name": "flipkart"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "resellers.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```